# Problem with isEqualToString: method and NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger

This is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<countingArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *element=[countingArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *source=[element objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSInteger count= [[element objectForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
    NSLog("source: %@",source); //Works
    NSLog("count %d",count);    //Don't Work! Error at this line

    for(int c=0; c<subscriptions.count; c++) {
        SubscriptionArray * element =[subscriptions objectAtIndex:c];
        NSLog(@"sorgente sub %@",element.source);
        NSLog(@"sorgente counting %@",source);
        if([source isEqualToString:element.source]) {
            element.count=count;
            [subscriptions replaceObjectAtIndex:c withObject:element];
            NSLog(@"equal"); 
            //this part of code is never been executed but I'm sure that
            //the if condition in some cases returns true
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to `NSLog("count %d",count);` my app crash without any information about.
I've also another problem with `if([source isEqualToString:element.source])` I'm sure that some times the condition return true... How can I remove blank space? Like the trim function in php? thanks

Comment: You need to explain what issues you are having with the code you have provided.

Comment: It would appear that they are never equal. What do your logs say?

Comment: I commented my code .... anyway I added some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
NSString *source=[element objectForKey:@"id"];
NSInteger count= [[element objectForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
```

to:

```
 NSString *source=[element valueForKey:@"id"];
 NSInteger count= [[element valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
```

For removing blank spaces you can try:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice the first two NSLog statements. They're both of the form `NSLog("something: %@", something)`. That is a C string literal, whereas NSLog takes an NSString for its format. This will lead to a crash. You want `NSLog(@"source: %@", source)`.